# Some JavaScript doesn't work on iPhone Safari once added to Home screen

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile-safari, progressive-web-apps

I have a simple JavaScript code that replaces the content of a div on button click. It replaces the content on every button click.

Subset of the code:

```
let template = document.querySelector(".template");
template.innerHTML = "content";  // this content is dynamic passed as argument to the function containing this code
```

It even works on iPhone iOS 10.2.1 Safari. But once added to the Home Screen it stops working !!

Unable to get any clue from any other sources.
What might be the issue ?

**Update**: Above issue seems to exist only when adding PWA (added to Home screen) while testing from localhost. JavaScript works fine once accessed accessed from web (online) ! Even more perplexing !!